# Expanding terrain without changing the original part in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, terrain

I have this map with mountains on the edges and a harbor with water at the bottom left corner.

I want to make it bigger but if I change the width or the length of
the terrain, it only stretches itself.

- So how could I make it bigger? I dont think that adding other terrains is a good solution.
- Or I have to delete the mountains and remake them deeper on the island?

[image]

Comment: _"I want to make it **bigger** but if I change the **width or the length** of the terrain, it only **stretches** itself.  I **dont** think that **adding other terrains** is a good solution"_ - well that's about it then

Comment: So are there only these 2 options?

Comment: I hope you find your answer, but I suggest you post your "btw another problem" section as a different question- it seems specific enough to warrant a few different detailed possibilities.

Comment: Okay, I did, thank you :)

Comment: _"Should I add water prefabs to the shore"_ - sure. Another option is to do what FSX and Lockheed Martin Prepar3D do and that is define layers; one which essentially describes metadata about different aspects of a mesh is (mountains; grass; beach; ocean) and another layer that contains the textures.  So I suspect there is no need for a ocean prefab in this scenario

Comment: 2 options? It all depends on what sort of landscape you are after.  Are you wanting a huge open world like Just Cause; Elder Scrolls?  They employ a solution where the very far but large (a distant mountain; a tall skyscraper) are always drawn because they draw a fake shrunken mountain at the back of the logarithmic-compressed z-buffer; and everything else in the scene is paged in as you traverse zones.  Or are you seeking a non-paged solution? (Just Cause makes much use of _impostors_ too)

Comment: Yes, I want an open world. Currently I am using Unity's standard asset, and I don't know how difficult is to make an ocean other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit the *Export Raw* button (in *Terrain Settings*), do whatever you want to the file that comes out (it will be an image file, so editing it the way you want shouldn't be difficult in something like Photoshop) and then use the *Import Raw* button to re-import the modified file.

EDIT: Unless you're trying to scale the terrain uniformly, in which case you should increase the height as well as the other dimensions.

Comment: Well this is a solution, but these images only contains height maps, so I would have to place objects, texturize the terrain etc. So I think I will stick to the old fashioned way. But thanks! :)